# Why disabling optimization is not working?

Tags: reactjs, webpacker

I have an issue of `Minified React error #130` at production, it works normally at development, but I have no idea what's at production.

I tried to disable the optimization, but it did not work, here is what I tried:

```
#config/webpack/production.js

process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'production'

const environment = require('./environment')

const config = environment.toWebpackConfig();
delete(config.optimization.minimizer);
config.optimization.minimize = false;
module.exports = config;
```

but it did not work, any idea why? how would I diagnose the issue?